# Javascript function in loop without click event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a slideshow, which I have working, but I can't get it to loop. I can't even get it to loop.

i want to loop this script without click event

currently i m using on click event to restart this script

```
 window.CP.exitedLoop(0);function rotateInfo() {
       var tl = new TimelineMax();

       tl.add("likely");
       tl.to($(".p1"), 0.3, {
         scale: 1.3,
         transformOrigin: "50% 100%",
         fill: $blue,
         ease: Bounce.easeOut },
       "likely").
       to($effect, 0.3, {
         y: -10,
         ease: Circ.easeOut },
       "likely").
       to($eLine, 0.3, {
         ease: Sine.easeOut },
       "likely").
       fromTo($(".d1"), 0.3, {
         opacity: 0,
         scale: 0.7 },
       {
         opacity: 1,
         scale: 1,
         ease: Back.easeOut },
       "likely").
       to($m1, 0.3, {
         fill: $green,
         ease: Circ.easeOut },
       "likely");

       tl.to($(".p1"), 0.3, {
         scale: 1,
         transformOrigin: "50% 100%",
         fill: $reg,
         ease: Back.easeIn },
       "likely+=1.25").
       to($effect, 0.3, {
         y: 0,
         ease: Circ.easeIn },
       "likely+=1.25").
       to($eLine, 0.3, {
         ease: Sine.easeIn },
       "likely+=1.25").
       to($(".d1"), 0.3, {
         opacity: 0,
         scale: 0.7 },
       "likely+=1.25").
       to($m1, 0.3, {
         fill: $mReg,
         ease: Circ.easeIn },
       "likely+=1.25");
       tl.to($circ, 1, {
         rotation: -41 },
       "likely+=1.25");

       tl.timeScale(0.7);


       return tl;

     }
     var master = new TimelineMax();
     master.add(rotateInfo(), "rotateInfo");

     $(document).on('click', 'a.replay', function (e) {
       master.restart();
       e.preventDefault();
     });
```

please help me to put this script in loop without click event. i want to remove click button or replay button

Answer (score 0):

use **interval** to do that . here is an example to use **interval** :

```
    setInterval(function(){

          master.restart();

    },1000); // repeat every 1s
```